# angular not showing jpeg from a blob using ng-src

Tags: image, angularjs, blob

I am new to angular and i spent a lot of time trying to figure it out hence:
This fragment works:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open( "GET",pic_url , true );
    xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
    xhr.onload = function( e ) {
            // Obtain a blob: URL for the image data.
            var arrayBufferView = new Uint8Array( this.response );
            var blob = new Blob( [ arrayBufferView ], { type: "image/jpeg" } );
            var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
            var imageUrl = urlCreator.createObjectURL( blob );
            var img = document.querySelector( "#sh_pic" );
            img.src = imageUrl;
    };
    xhr.send();
```

when I try to do it the angular way:
keeping it simple in the controller:

```
 delete $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With']
 $http.get(pic_url,{ headers: { responseType: 'blob'}} //arraybuffer
           ).success(function(response){ 
                     var arrayBufferView = new Uint8Array(response);
                     var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                     var blob = new Blob( [ arrayBufferView ], { type: "image/jpeg" } );
                     var imageUrl = urlCreator.createObjectURL( blob );
                     var sceImageUrl= $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(imageURL); //with or without
                     $scope.http_blob_pic_url = sceImageUrl ;
            });
```

and in the config:

```
    $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist(['self','**']);
    $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|file|blob):|data:image\//)
and 
<img id="http_blobImgId" ng-src="{{http_blob_pic_url}}" width=100 />
```

Not getting any errors and the blob's generated url is in the ng-src and src attributes in the img tag.
Still no picture in the browser.
I tried to tweak it with:  responseType blob/arraybuffer with different bases, urlCreator, URL, $window, .., CORS, sce, checked in angular's source how they process the response string and the JSON treatment, transformresponse of $http, putting fragment above in service, redone all promise variations possible, tried all var declaration to go as locals in the controller and as $rootScope and and checked the $apply so on. I coudn't find anything in the net, apart from errors concerning the $sce, $compile and so on. So I assume I am doing something very wrong in order to fail to do such a basic thing.
A bit lost already please help.
Thanks